# How do you delete and append values to an array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am a beginner in c++ and I am wondering how do you delete and append values to arrays.

What I mean is like this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

I want to turn it into:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3}
```

by deleting the last value of the array.

Also,

I would like to know how to append the a value to the end of an array. Like this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Into this:

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a vector if you need dynamic resizing. Arrays are for when you know exactly how much memory you need. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: What reggae said: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/vector.html

Comment: See the SO C++ documentation of arrays at (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays/10246/a-dynamic-size-matrix-using-stdvector-for-storage#t=201608172209182527323).

Comment: never mind thanks alot.

Comment: I meant (http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/3017/arrays/10243/dynamically-sized-raw-array#t=201608172211035032625), but the keyboard and SO's interface conspired to not let me post it.

Comment: thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: @Ian - Also, even if you knew the exact number of entries and did not change the size dynamically, use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and not dumb C++ arrays: `std::array<int, 4> arr = {{1,2,3,4}};`

Answer (score 3):

You can't, without `new`/`delete`, but `std::vector` is better. Here's an example of both.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    // With new/delete:
    int *array = new int[3];
    array[0] = 1;
    array[1] = 2;
    array[2] = 3;

    // `array` processing...

    int *array2 = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        // copy old data into new array (array2)
        array2[i] = array[i];
    }
    array2[3] = 4;
    delete []array;

    // `array2` processing...

    delete []array2;

    // With STL vector:
    std::vector<int> array3;
    array3.resize(3);
    array3[0] = 1;
    array3[1] = 2;
    array3[2] = 3;

    // `array3` processing...

    // Add any number of elements
    array3.push_back(4);

    // resized `array3` processing...
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using single quotes in comments of code snippets! The habits that we get into :) :)

Comment: It's not very nice to point a beginner towards `new` and `delete`. Point beginners, *and* experienced, for that matter, towards `std::vector`. Thank you.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I did in the code; edited this answer for clarity. Also already linked a std::vector tutorial in the question comments.